# My sorting algorithm runtime errors

Tags: algorithm

I developed the following sorting algorithm but there are some run time errors that I cant figure out. The program terminates when it comes to the part of filling the array. I'm still a beginner in ada so I couldn't figure out where the problem is...

```
With Ada.Text_IO;
With Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
Use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
Use Ada.Text_IO;

Procedure sort is
   n,i,x : Integer;


   -- Max_Heapify Function...
   Procedure Max_Heapify ( i, n : integer) is 
      j, Temp : Integer;
   begin
      Temp:=Int_Acc(i);
      j:=2*i;

         if Temp>Int_Acc(j) then


         elsif Temp<=Int_Acc(j) then
            Int_Acc(j/2):=Int_Acc(j);
            j:=2*j;
         end if;
      end loop;
      Int_Acc(j/2):=Temp;
   end Max_Heapify;


begin
   Get(n);
      for i in MyArr'range loop
         Put_Line("Enter Element " & Integer'Image(i));
         Get(MyArr(i));
      end loop;
   end;
end sort;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does your compiler not output an actual error message, perhaps with a stack trace or (at least) an indicator of the line that it fails on?

Comment: The compiler clearly won't output anything for a runtime error : it's good, but it can't see the future! However (assuming Gnat) compiling with the right flags, the runtime exception will give a stack trace which addr2line can translate into source locations. In my experience, spookily close to what went wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is that you are insisting on writing Ada code using c - Style programming paradigms.

**Firstly**:

The declarations:

```
   Type Arr is array(1..20) of Integer;
   Type int_access is access Arr;
   MyArr : int_access;
```

Where you use `Int_Acc : in out int_access` as parameters to procedures are useless in Ada. You are trying to pass a pointer to an array in (which you are doing!), but you should just pass your `Type Arr` as `in out` - The Ada compiler knows to do this as a pointer!

**Secondly**:

I cannot see where you actually allocate any memory to `MyArr`. This is a possible source of your runtime error. (when you write to or index an array that does not exist, i would expect to have a problem!)

**Thirdly**:
You seem to be mixing fixed length arrays with variable length input. If N > 20, you will have a problem.

**Fourthly**:
[Insulting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729858/my-heap-sorting-algorithm-runtime-errors#comment34641789_22729962) the language is not the best way of getting help from those who like it.

Comment: @NMWS What you mentioned is perfectly the right solution. But about the point of N>20... How can I solve this problem, is there is a way I can  add size to my array?

Comment: For an array of the correct size N, see the first part of my answer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I solved the problem of the runtime error, but it seems there is another problem; the subprograms are mostly not called... The code is updated above. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @BrianDrummond the code above is updated with a variable sized array. But still the subprograms are mostly not called.

Comment: And there's a good but more subtle reason for that : the for loop bounds are empty ranges, reversed... see edit to my answer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond you didnot change a line of code sir :)

Comment: apologies I was called away before I could finish the edit : now up.

Answer (score 1):

NWS has nailed it : there is a pointer, but no array there.

But it's clear that you have learned C, which leaves you with a lot to learn about other languages including Ada. There really are better ways of doing many things, that aren't taught to C programmers because C doesn't allow them.

---

Allocating variable sized arrays without pointers, malloc and free for example...

```
Type Arr is array(positive range <>) of Integer;   -- of any size

begin
   Put_Line("Enter Number Of Elements Of Array");
   Get(n);
   declare    -- now we know the size
      My_Arr : Arr(1 .. n);
   begin      -- My_Arr is in scope until the end of this block
      ...
   end;
end sort;
```

---

Using the type system better...

**Bad** programming :

```
   for i in 1 .. n loop
      Get(MyArr(i));
   end loop;
   HeapSort(MyArr,n);
   for i in 1 .. n loop
      Put_Line(Integer'Image(MyArr(i)));
   end loop;
```

This is bad because it violates the DRY principle : loop bounds repeated, and something that hopefully represents the array size passed around as a separate parameter... a maintenance nightmare if you decide to rename `n` to something meaningful for example.

**better** programming : Use the type system. Recognise that merely declaring an array has declared a new subtype of integer, representing the index of the array. You can access it as `My_Arr'range`, and the high bound as `My_Arr'last`.

```
   for i in My_Arr'range loop
      Get(MyArr(i));
   end loop;
   HeapSort(MyArr);
   for i in My_Arr'range loop
      Put_Line(Integer'Image(MyArr(i)));
   end loop;
```

And accidents such as redefining n after the array declaration can no longer generate buffer overflows. 
NOTE: Heapsort now gets its range from the array. (Max_Heapify may still need a separate parameter to operate on subsets of the array)

**Arguably best** - if it makes the intent clearer - name the index datatype explicitly and use it...

```
   declare    -- now we know the size
      subtype My_Range is positive range 1 .. n;
      My_Arr : Arr(My_Range);
   begin      -- My_Arr is in scope until the end of this block
      for i in My_Range loop ...
```

---

And lastly, which do you prefer; a Storage_Error exception immediately the bug occurs (writing to memory you forgot to allocate) or something odd happening much later because something scribbled across another variable?

---

EDIT

Having cleared up the major issues two more subtle ones remain...

If I compile the modified program (in Gnat 4.8) I get several warnings : one of them is important and tells you exactly what the problem is...

Most of the warnings stem from the fact that

```
for i in My_Arr'range loop
```

declares its own loop variable `i` which hides any existing in-scope declaration. So you can tidy up the code by removing the unnecessary declarations.

What remains is:

> sort.adb:51:28: warning: loop range may be null
>   sort.adb:51:28: warning: bounds may be wrong way round

The for loop bounds are empty ranges, reversed...

- `1 .. 3` declares a subtype with 3 values
- `reverse 1 .. 3` declares the same subtype and iterates backwards over it.
- But `3 .. 1` declares an EMPTY subtype (containing NO valid values) so iterating over it - either way round - does precisely *nothing*.

Hopefully that is the missing part of the puzzle. I'm not clear why one faulty loop gets this warning while the other (at line 38) doesn't...

Comment: perfectly informative @Brian. You helped me alot :)

Comment: And leaving the one at line 38 as-is results in a **reverse** sort! Amazing and unexpected.

Comment: Mr. Brian you helped me a lot today... much appreciated sir. god bless you :) @SimonWright thank you so much sir :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   if j<n **and then** Int_Acc(j+1)>Int_Acc(j) then
            j:=j+1;
```

I think you want just 'and' instead of 'and then,' although I haven't looked at Ada code in years.

Did that compile?

Comment: This is not the problem, but thanks anyway. Ada is the most retarded lang I've ever seen

Comment: No, you really DO want `and then` to specify the order of the operations, and avoid optimiser scheduling the (potentially out of range) array access before the check. Arguably its the languages that allow one or other of these strategies but not both, that are retarded.